# IMAP Credentials working @Outlook webclient, but AuthenticationFailedException while polling using Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I am using Spring Integration for email polling.

**Scenario :**

1. In our DEV environment, there are **6 DEV mailboxes** are available.
2. All mail accounts are using the **same** password.**Technically**, mail usernames are also **same** - like abc-dev1, abc-dev2,abc-qa1, abc-qa2 etc.
3. **Spring Boot+Spring Integration** application is polling these 6 mailboxes for any unread emails.
4. **Result:** mail polling **success for 3** mail boxes and **fails** while poll **other 3** mailboxes.

**Exception:**

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
       [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : 
           org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException:
              failure occurred while polling for mail; 
              nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

---

**From the exception log**, it **seems like** username/password is wrong, But that is **not** the case, I can login (using **Outlook** web client) to these mailboxes ( all 6 ) using same credentials.

I **carefully** verified/typed credentials, but no luck.

**Question:** Is this `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException` **misleading?** Is there something to fix at mail server/firewall etc?

Any clues?

**PS:** I already enabled mail debugging (mail.debug = true), But that is not printing anything in eclipse console.

Comment: The fact that you can login does not mean so much. Additional information would help: are you using a third-party mail-serverl? It may think you are a bot (you are) and are trying to do a mail-bombing attack. Have you checked the credentials used for all the successful requests to see if you are using the mailboxes you mentioned? Etc. I believe you have to debug more and provide more context.

Comment: If you can't find the JavaMail debug output, use Session.setDebugOut to redirect it to a file.  Are you connecting to Gmail?  Have you [enabled less secure apps](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmailauth)?

Comment: I am connecting to Outlook (Microsoft Exchange Server) and using Secure  IMAP (imaps)

Comment: If `imaps`, maybe something wrong with SSL certificate ?